# Mother name is different on my passport

Tags: usa, passports, indian-citizens

My mother name is different on my passport and her passport. And i do not have any document to show her name which is written on my passport. So thinking of changing passport to correct mother name on my passport. How can i change my mother name on my indian passport in USA?

Comment: Do you really need to change it while you are still in the USA?

Comment: It should not cause them any visa problem in future, so....

Comment: You need to discuss the concerned organization. Now a days, technology has improved. You may can change it from there itself.

Comment: Why do you think it is important to have the correct name? I think nobody care about it (and in most countries is also not written).

Comment: Please explain why you think the spelling of your mother's name matters?